# How to extract images from a flash image-viewer?

Tags: images, flash, cache, extract

I need to download a number of pages of a magazine issue which is available via online viewer made in Flash. The player loads a page image and allows to scroll it.

Is it possible to extract the image from flash cache data?

Simple screenshots don't work in this case, because the images are larger than my screen, and merging parts would be too time consuming - I would like to avoid this.

Comment: Which OS are you using?  Which browser?  There are tools for Linux (and such) like mencoder or pacpl... and browsers will tend to cache the files in /tmp like /tmp/FlashXyZ23 (for example).  You can generally copy the cache to your home directory and run the file through the converter.

Comment: Maybe [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1341534/707788) helps.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have the flash file then you can convert it into images using this free software

[SWF To Image GUI 1.00](http://www.topshareware.com/SWF-To-Image-GUI-download-59935.htm)

Comment: I would be happy to have just flash file with images to see them offline. However, normally, the flash file doesn't contain images, and downloads them on demand. So when one saves it and then opens - it gives an error message.

Answer (score 1):

Clunky, but I've used LiveHttpHeaders sometimes to see the URL, then download the file myself.  Obviously only tolerable for a small number of images.

Comment: Looks great - I have got swf files for each page. So now I just need to find a good way to extract the images...

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to something similar for JCPenney Portraits viewer, and was able to do it by simply capturing all the image requests going out using the "Live HTTP Headers" extension for Firefox. Just extract all URL's into a file, say `urls.txt` and use `wget -i urls.txt` (or create a shell script with a wget line for each and specify `-O <filename>` and run the script).